# Нужно удалить повторяющиеся пары значений в списке при этом первая пара значений должна остаться

Tags: python, list

Вроде с удалением разобрался но не понимаю как сделать так чтоб первый for реагировал на изменение длинны списка. Буду благодарен за любую помощь.

```
n = [2,3,5,2,3]
m = [2,4,6,2,4]
L = 5
p = []
for i in range(L-1): #проверка на повторы
  p.clear()
  p.append(n[i])
  p.append(m[i])
  i = 0
  for j in range(len(n)):
    if p[0] == n[j] and p[1] == m[j]:
      i += 1
    if i > 1:
     n.pop(n[j])
     m.pop(m[j])
     L -= 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вариант, если нужно сохранить последовательность пар:

```
n = [2,3,5,2,3]
m = [2,4,6,2,4]
uniq = set()
print([uniq.add(p) or p for p in zip(n, m) if p not in uniq])
[(2, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
n = [2,3,5,2,3]
m = [2,4,6,2,4]

print( * set(zip(n, m)))

(5, 6) (3, 4) (2, 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

У меня вроде вот так получилось.

```
for i in range(L-1): #проверка на повторы
  p.clear()
  p.append(n[i])
  p.append(m[i])
  i = 0
  for j in range(len(n)):
    if p[0] == n[j] and p[1] == m[j]:
      i += 1
    if i > 1:
      n[j] = 0
      m[j] = 0
for i in range(n.count(0)):
  n.remove(0)
  m.remove(0)
```